# Is it possible to select multiple rows in a treeview widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Is it possible to select multiple rows in a treeview widget?, further, how do you then get the input/selected rows.

Here is a treeview I have created, however it is not possible for me to select both rows.

[image: treeview]

If this is not possible, is their a widget in tkinter or ttk which allows for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get a tuple of the selected items using `selection()` method. Once you get the tuple, you can access each item using the `item()` method. Here is an example.

P.S. In the code, select multiple items by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and clicking on rows and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk

def select():
    curItems = tree.selection()
    tk.Label(root, text="\n".join([str(tree.item(i)['values']) for i in curItems])).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
tree = tkinter.ttk.Treeview(root, height=4)

tree['show'] = 'headings'
tree['columns'] = ('Badge Name', 'Requirement', 'Cost', 'Difficulty')
tree.heading("#1", text='Badge Name', anchor='w')
tree.column("#1", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#2", text='Requirement', anchor='w')
tree.column("#2", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#3", text='Cost', anchor='w')
tree.column("#3", stretch="no")
tree.heading("#4", text='Difficulty', anchor='w')
tree.column("#4", stretch="no")
tree.pack()

tree.insert("", "end", values=["IT Badge", "Track Computer", "$1.50", "2"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["Selfless Badge", "Track Yourself", "$100.50", "10"])
tree.insert("", "end", values=["Tracking Badge", "Track Animal", "$4.50", "7"])

tree.bind("<Return>", lambda e: select())

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: I cannot seem to select multiple rows in the treeview. The information does get submitted upon enter pressed, and does appear on the tkinter window.

Comment: @LyraOrwell You can select multiple rows by pressing Ctrl and then clicking on rows.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I did not know that, maybe you should add that to your answer. Just for folks like me.

Comment: @LyraOrwell Done. Thanks for the feedback.